# Find the first instance of a value looking backward in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Timestamp   Value
11/23/2017  7
11/24/2017  3
11/25/2017  5
11/26/2017  7
11/27/2017  7
11/28/2017  7
```

I want to write something which returns the first instance of the last value, 7, looking upward, and stops when the value changes to something else. So the answer to the sample dataframe should be `11/26/2017`.

I tried to `drop_duplicates`but that returns the first row with timestamp `11/23/2017`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create helper `Series` for get unique consecutive values of column `Value`, get index of max value by[`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and last select value by `loc`:

```
print (df)
    Timestamp  Value
0  11/23/2017      7
1  11/24/2017      3
2  11/25/2017      5
3  11/26/2017      7
4  11/27/2017      7
5  11/28/2017      7

a = df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()
b = df.loc[a.idxmax(), 'Timestamp']
print (b)
11/26/2017
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    4
Name: Value, dtype: int32
```

---

If first column is index solution is simplier, because need index value by `max` of `Series`:

```
print (df)
            Value
Timestamp        
11/23/2017      7
11/24/2017      3
11/25/2017      5
11/26/2017      7
11/27/2017      7
11/28/2017      7

b = df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum().idxmax()
print (b)
11/26/2017
```

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the speed ;-)

Comment: Thanks for testing! I just tested it against 600.000 rows DF - my solution was bit faster... ;-)

Comment: `4ms`? It is same here ;)

Comment: In my opinion it depends of real data, I try test it too in big `df` with your setup and get same timings `In [303]: %timeit df.iat[df.loc[::-1, 'Value'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0).idxmax()+1, df.columns.get_loc('Timestamp')]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop`

`In [304]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()
     ...: b = df.loc[a.idxmax(), 'Timestamp']
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop`

Comment: sure, it always depends on real data

Answer (score 2):

```
In [173]: df.iat[df.loc[::-1, 'Value'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0).idxmax()+1,
                 df.columns.get_loc('Timestamp')]
Out[173]: '11/26/2017'
```

**Timing** for 600.000 rows DF:

```
In [201]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [202]: %%timeit
     ...: df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum().idxmax()
     ...:
15.3 ms ± 646 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [203]: %%timeit
     ...: df.iat[df.loc[::-1, 'Value'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0).idxmax()+1,
     ...:        df.columns.get_loc('Timestamp')]
     ...:
11.6 ms ± 237 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```